# How to designate a url to a radio button selection

Tags: javascript, html, ajax, asp.net-mvc-5

I have a view with a content area. What I want to do is load a partial view into that div area, depending on which radio button is selected.  I am pretty new to all of this, but I have spent some time looking at similar examples.  I have gotten this to work with buttons, but radio buttons look a bit more professional

Index View (which partial views will be loaded)

```
<fieldset id="partials">
    @Html.RadioButton("partials", false, new { id = "Supplies" }) Add Supplies
    @Html.RadioButton("partials", false, new { id = "Forms" }) Add Forms
</fieldset>

<div id="divContent" data-listen="start_date end_date" data-contentrequest="_Summary" data-requestonload="true">

</div>
```

I found some Ajax code, from online, that sort of works . . but I am stuck a bit:

```
<script type="text/javascript"> 
$(function () {
    $('#partials input[type=radio]').on('change', function () {                  
        $.ajax({
                     type: "get",
                     cache: false,
                     url: $(this).data('url'),
                     success: function (data, xhr, settings) {
                         $("#divContent").html(data);
                     }

                 });
             });
            });
```

AS IS - No matter what radio button is selected, the Index View loads itself within the divContent area.

What I want to do is load ICSNewOrders/AddSupplies (partial view) if the 'Supplies' radio option is selected, and load the ICSNewOrders/AddForms (partial view) if the 'Forms' radio option is selected

I know that somehow I need to send the url from each radio option to the Ajax - I just don't know how.

1. Where in the Radio Button can I overload it with the url?  I have tried many different ways without success.
2. Will that automatically send the specific url to the Ajax, or is there another step?

I have gotten this to work with buttons, easy enough

```
<div>
<button data-url='@Url.Action("AddForms","ICSNewOrders")'>Add Forms To Order</button>
<button data-url='@Url.Action("AddSupplies","ICSNewOrders")'>Add Supplies To Order</button>
```

I am not having any luck doing the same for Radio Button.

Update:  As requested, I am adding the final html rendered version of radio buttons

```
<fieldset id="partials">
    <input id="Supplies" name="partials" type="radio" value="False" /> Add Supplies
    <input id="Forms" name="partials" type="radio" value="False" /> Add Forms

</fieldset>
```

Comment: can u please share the final browser rendered version of the radio buttons?

Comment: Hi @RonitMukherjee.  I have added the browser rendered version of the radio buttons to my original post.

Comment: your rendered version of radio doesn't include "data-url"

Comment: That's my basic question. I know how to add 'data-url' to a regular button (shown in my post).  But I can't find anything online that shows me how to add data-url to my radio button options?  I have tried numerous ways and all I get are errors.

Comment: @Html.RadioButton("partials", false, new { id = "Supplies",data-url="example.com" }) Add Supplies - Try This

Comment: @RonitMukherjee - thank you for your effort.  I really appreciate it.  Unfortunately, this gave me errors that I could not resolve. I found another way to achieve my goal.  Thank you

Answer (score 0):

I, eventually, found a good example online and modified it to fit my needs.  Slightly different than what I was working on.  Here is what I did, in case someone else needs to do something similar:

I have an index view with a Data Container and two partial views that are hidden.  The concept is that I will use radio buttons to swap out the two partial views into the Data Container.

Index View

```
<div>
    Add Forms to Order :@Html.RadioButton("orders", "Forms", new { onclick = "showResult(this)" })
    Add Supplies to Order :@Html.RadioButton("orders", "Supplies", new { onclick = "showResult(this)" })
</div>

<div id="divContent" data-listen="start_date end_date" data-contentrequest="_Summary" data-requestonload="true">
</div>

<div id="AddSuppliesPart" style="display: none">     
    @Html.Action("AddSupplies")
</div>    
<div id="AddFormsPart" style="display: none">
   @Html.Action("AddForms")
</div>
```

Jscript

```
<script type="text/javascript">
function showResult(radio) {
    //alert("yes");
    var selected = radio.value;
    if (selected == "Forms")
        document.getElementById("divContent").innerHTML
            = document.getElementById("AddFormsPart").innerHTML;


    else if (selected == "Supplies")
        document.getElementById("divContent").innerHTML
            = document.getElementById("AddSuppliesPart").innerHTML;
}
</script>
```